# System process using constantly 20% CPU - Windows 7 Pro 64

Tags: windows-7, cpu

In my Windows 7 Professional 64 bit I see the system process using 20% of CPU constantly. This also tends to rise the CPU temperature, causing the fan to start, and in general slowing down the entire system.

The PC is a HP laptop, with 4GB of ram.

Using Process Explorer, double clicking the system process, I see that the most CPU consuming threads are from `ntoskrnl.exe`, as in the image below:

[image: the image below.]

I tried a memory check, and also some hints found in the net, no results.
The question is: what can I try to find a solution? I need a direction...

[image: this is the screenshot from process explorer]

Comment: Condition persist in safe mode?

Comment: the most common cause for this (and I'm guessing this is occuring within the `System` process) is that it's usually a kernel-mode driver misbehaving; so, first port of call is to find the latest drivers for everything you possibly can.

Comment: Take a look at the thread stack of the threads that are using the CPU and see what modules are listed as callers on the stack.  That will show you which driver is causing the problem.

Comment: @shf301 how can I check the callers? using process explorer (sysinternals) if I double click on a thread I get a "unable to access thread" error

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I restarted in safe mode with networking, and everything was ok. Does this mean that I have a driver problem or a software one?

Comment: It could be either, but this tells you that the condition goes away well on startup programs are disabled, and potentially networking... just a good place to start the process of elimination in my book. Did you update the drivers? Just go down the list, system board, NIC, video, sound...